# Oracle - Combine rows

Tags: oracle11g

I need to combine 2 rows from multiple table as single row in oracle 11g
The 2 rows should be replaced with a single row and the column values for the new row should be the sum of the two 2 rows

Existing

```
Id No   Region  Value1  Value 2 Value 3

1           A       5       2       3
2           B       2       4       1
3           C       2       2       2
4           D       1       1       1
```

New Change

```
Id No   Region  Value1  Value 2 Value 3
1           x       7       6       4
2           C       2       2       2
3           D       1       1       1
```

Comment: On what conditions? You're combining A & B here but there's no obvious reason why...

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359809/combining-data-in-multiple-rows/23360163#23360163

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this table:

```
Id No   Region  Value1  Value 2 Value 3

1           A       5       2       3
2           B       2       4       1
```

You can combine 2 rows if it has same values in one or more columns..

If you insist to combine this 2 rows(like your example) then the query should be like this:

```
SELECT '1' as Id_no, 'x' as region, sum(value1), sum(value2), sum(value3) from table_name
```