# Combining data in multiple rows

Tags: oracle11g

I'm following a SQL tutorial and am having trouble with this problem where I have multiple rows with the same order#-- how can I consolidate all rows with the same order# into just one row?

So for example, in the screenshot, the first 2 rows are about "Jake Lucas" and have the same order#: what do I need to do to make these 2 rows into 1 row?

Here's my code:

```
SELECT firstName || ' ' || lastname "Name", customer#, order#, quantity, 
paideach, (quantity * paideach) "TOTAL", state

FROM orderitems JOIN orders USING (order#) JOIN customers USING (customer#)

WHERE (state = 'FL' OR state = 'GA');
```

[image]

Comment: what you mean combinin data ?

Comment: customer#, order# never comes to same ? and please say if they are the same what do you want

Comment: I mean, how can I combine all rows where the order# is the same and make it into one row?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your syntax format, It seems you are using a framework or so..

But if you want to combine the same order# then you can check out GROUP BY SQL Statement..

You can try to put it after the WHERE clause, try `... WHERE (state = 'FL' OR state = 'GA') GROUP BY (order#)`

more details:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: I'm gettting a "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: I believe it's because you have different value in quantity, paideach and total for the same name, customer#, order#. So you have 2 options, either not to select the quantity, paideach and total or to use aggregate function such as MAX,MIN,SUM or else for 
quantity, paideach and total..

Comment: If I were to use SUM, how do I tell it to sum the quantity for rows with the same order#?

Comment: I don't know about your syntax format, but I guess it should be like this: SELECT .... , SUM(quantity) , .... FROM ..... and so on..

Here is more detail explanation about the error: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00979_not_a_group_by_expression.htm

Comment: Try this SELECT query:

SELECT firstName || ' ' || lastname "Name", customer#, order#, SUM(quantity), 
SUM(paideach), SUM(quantity * paideach) "TOTAL", state

AND for the GROUP BY, try this:

GROUP BY order#, Name, customer#, STATE

Check out this link : http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00979.php

Comment: I think you mean summation of values where the order # same.